# Cannot create file database.mdf because it already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I want to display data in view from my database but some strange problem is appears.

Error:

> Cannot create file
>   '~\MyProject\MyProject\App_Data\BlogContext.mdf'
>   because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and
>   retry the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed
>   could not be created. Check related errors.

View(cshtml):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller ActionResult Post:

```
public ActionResult Post()
        {
            return View(db.Posts.ToList());
        }
```

Post Model:

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShortContent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Meta { get; set; }
    public virtual string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Published { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

    public virtual PostCategory PostCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual List<string> Tags { get; set; }
```

}

I don't what Visual want to do, because It's true i already have a db called that way, but i dont want to make a new. I just want to use this one.

What to do?

Comment: were you able to find solution to it?

Comment: Yes. When I update my db and then added migration, everything started to working good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used:

```
update-database
```

and

```
add-migration
```

commands to fix this problem.