# Entity Framework - Cannot create file because it already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to set up a connection to a service-based database in Visual Studio, for a university project. Currently, I have entities set up to model the specific tables that I need (a credentials table for a login page). I have also set up a `DbContext`, which implements an `SqlConnectionFactory`.

However, whenever I call on the `DbContext` in a LINQ query, I always get this exception:

[image: Cannot create file because it already exists]

This is despite the fact that I am not trying to create a new database, but to access an existing one.

**DbConfiguration**

```
public class SoftStocksDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SoftStocksDBConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\...\\SoftStocksDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"));
        this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }

}
```

**DBContext**

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(SoftStocksDBConfiguration))]
public class SoftStocksDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Credential> Credentials { get; set; }
}
```

Using the DbContext in the login:

```
Credential credential;

using (var db = new SoftStocksDBContext())
{
    credential = db.Credentials
                   .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Username == userName && 
                                        c.Password == password);
}
...
```

I have tried using different values for the connection string to verify that the connection is correct.

I have tried using `LocalDbConnectionFactory` instead of `SqlConnectionFactory`

I have tried enabling code-First migrations, and ensuring that my entities were up-to-date and mapped correctly.

As I had an issue in that I could only access records that were programmatically added, I tried loading in the data using `db.Credentials.Load()`

I have tried restarting Visual Studio.

I have tried closing the database connection from the GUI.

I have tried using different parameters in the connection string, such as `Initial Catalog`.

I have tried running `update-database` as specified [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926342/cannot-create-file-database-mdf-because-it-already-exists) but I get the same error message as above.

Comment: Don't use the `AttachDbFileName=` feature anymore - it causes a lot of confusion and grief, and will be removed from SQL Server in a future version anyway - better stay away from it today already! See Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits : Using AttachDBFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info on this.

Comment: I've removed `AttachDbFileName=` but I still get the same error. I've tried overwriting the migration and updating the database again, but I also get the same error. For reference, my connection string is now `Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True`